# Javascript/jQuery gives weird result from addition

Tags: javascript, jquery, addition

I'm just starting javascript and jquery and now I'm stuck with this kind of problem:

```
var myCharacter = ('#myCharacter').css('top'); // gives 140px
var numberOnly = myCharacter.replace('px',''); // gives 140
var total = numberOnly + 20; // gives 14020 not 160
```

I just don't understand why this happens.

Comment: Because `numberOnly` is a string and if you try to add an integer to it it automatically coerces the integer to a string.

Comment: `('#myCharacter').css('top');` should read `$('#myCharacter').css('top');`

Comment: `var total = +numberOnly + 20;` or you could use directly `parseInt()` (with radix  even here doesn't really matter): `var total = parseInt($('#myCharacter').css('top'), 10) + 20;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need `parseInt()`

```
var total = parseInt(numberOnly) + 20;
```

because `numberOnly` is a string, not a number, so its adding a number to a string which results in that 14020 as a string

Answer (score 1):

When you replace 'px' in '140px', you end up with a variable of string type. (javascript has types, but they are dynamic)

When you call '140'+20, the type is not converted automatically, because + is an operation that makes sense on strings: concatenation.

You should explicitly convert to a number, for example by using parseInt('140'), then the addition should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As one of the operands in `numberOnly + 20` is a string, the `+` operator does string concatenation, not addition.

Use the `parseInt` method to parse the string to a number, then you don't have to remove the `px` part either, as the parsing ends when it encounters non-numerical characters.

```
var myCharacter = parseInt(('#myCharacter').css('top'), 10);
var total = myCharacter + 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `numberOnly`  is a `String` you can cast to `int` by doing:

```
var total = +numberOnly + 20
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myCharacter = ('#myCharacter').css('top'); // gives 140px
var numberOnly = myCharacter.replace('px',''); // gives 140
var total = parseInt(numberOnly) + 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to add up with string  so first convert it into integer,use `parseInt()` to do this:

```
var total = parseInt(numberOnly) + 20;//160
```

Answer (score -1):

`numberOnly` is still of type `string`, i.e. it's a number of characters. Thus you currently conctenate string '140' with 20, which is implicitly converted to a string.

To fix this, convert `numberOnly` to an integer using `[parseInt][1]`.